# Post simple value in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I try to POST a simple request to InfluxDB to know "How much VMs are UP ?" in my Grafana Dashboard.

I think I go wrong somewhere, because my value is not reachable.

It's my cURL command :

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://server:8086/write?db=DBname' --data-binary 'vm_up value=14 1448596134'
```

If a key is necessary, it can be "server=dom0".

Can you help me ?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer, is about timestamp.

I need at precision=s to URL :

```
http://server:8086/write?db=DBname&precision=s'
```

Comment: By default all timestamps submitted to InfluxDB are assumed to be in nanoseconds since epoch. The points you submitted with 10-digit timestamps and no precision parameter should be in the database with timestamps a few seconds after midnight, Jan 1, 1970.